# Can't access "Entity Framework" tab in solution explorer VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I want to use "Reverse Engineer Code First" feature. When I right click on project in solution explorer there is no tab "Entity Framework"!! I installed Entity Framework package via nuget package manager.

So, do I need to install something else, or mabby there is another way to access "Reverse Engineer Code First" in Visual Studio 2012 ??
Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Entity Framework Powertools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d), a Visual Studio Extension.